# Querying with ndb.ComputedProperty

Tags: python, app-engine-ndb

My computer property is defined like this:

```
class User(app.Model)
  DEFAULT_GPLUS_IMG_URL == "http://someimage.com/image/image.png"

  has_avatar = ndb.ComputedProperty(
    lambda self: True if self.avatar == DEFAULT_GPLUS_IMG_URL else False)

  @property
  def avatar(self):
    return self.gplus_data.get('image')
```

I am attempting to query like this in Interactive Console:

```
from google.appengine.ext import ndb
from app.lib.users import User

print User.query(User.has_avatar==True).fetch()
```

This returns an `[]`.

But when I loop through the `User.query()` like this:

```
for i in User.query():
  print i.has_avatar
```

I get `[True, False]`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you boil it down to a self-contained example? This ought to work, so I see two possibilities: either there's something wrong in code you haven't shown us, or you're falling victim to eventual consistency (Google it).

Comment: I added more of my User class with relevant info. I just looked up eventual consistency though, and it seems that that was the problem. My query works today. Should I be expecting this kind of latency when dealing with queries in ndb datastores? This was done in a dev environment with `dev_appserver`

Comment: IIRC the dev server simulates eventual consistency quite aggressively. You might want to answer this yourself and accept your own answer (that's totally okay in StackOverflow).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Guido pointed out in the comments to the question, the issue was related to `dev_appserver` cacheing. I was able to get the correct results the next day.